# How to remove the password of the SD card in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: password, sd-card, password-recovery

I forgot the password of my micro SD card. How can i remove the password of the SD in ubuntu 12.04. I tried using system files in mobile but it did not successes.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 has passed its End-of-life date, and is no longer supported on AskUbuntu.

Comment: @waltinator This question was asked in 2014, when it was on topic. See [Please don't flag old questions as EOL](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/16132/124466)

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi I used to agree with you, but this question is actually just a waste of space and sends users on a wild goose chase. Cracking passwords should not have been on topic in 2014 and it should not be on topic now, IMHO. Besides the answer does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are looking to crack the SD card, so recovering the password will work fine as well. Luckily, this is pretty easy for most SD cards since it is stored in plain text. You should be able to just follow the instructions posted here to gain the access you require.

### Steps

1. Put your SD card in your card reader
2. Mount your SD card by running `sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0` from Terminal
3. Open up the SD card in your file manager
4. Find a file called MMCSTORE and copy it
5. Paste it wherever you want
6. Open it with your text editor
7. Now, you should see your password in plain text

### How it Works

This works because by copy-pasting the MMCSTORE file you can gain read-write access to the pasted version. So, you can simply open the file and view it's contents. For more information, view [this webpage](http://engineerspride.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-hack-or-unlock-micro-sd-card.html).

Comment: The problem is SD card not showing in ubuntu after putting it to card reader

Comment: **mount: can't find /dev/mmcblk0 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab** this is the reply